# com.mongodb.client.MongoClient overridden by com.mongodb.MongoClient

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have MongoConfig:

```java
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoClients;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Configuration
public class MongoConfig{

    public @Bean
    MongoClient mongo() {
        MongoClient mongo = MongoClients.create("mongodb://test:123456@localhost/test");
        return mongo;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() throws Exception {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongo(), "test");
    }

}
```

build.gradle:

```
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-mongodb', version: '3.0.0.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-sync', version: '4.0.4'
```

spring-data-mongodb repository [README](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb) specifically says that is upgraded as:

> mongo:mongo-client -> com.mongodb.MongoClient ->
>   com.mongodb.client.MongoClient for upgrade 2.x -> 3.x

But, the following error comes:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: 
Failed to instantiate 
[org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate]: 
Factory method 'mongoTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
@Bean method MongoConfig.mongo called as bean reference for type 
[com.mongodb.client.MongoClient] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type 
[com.mongodb.MongoClient]. Overriding bean of same name declared in: 
class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]
```

note that:

```
[com.mongodb.client.MongoClient] but overridden by non-compatible bean instance of type [com.mongodb.MongoClient]
```

What is the issue with the current setup?

Comment: Have you checked the class called out by: `Overriding bean of same name declared in: class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/mongo/MongoAutoConfiguration.class]